# Replace in a select without adding a new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, replace

Consider this data:

```
col1  | col2
kk|kk | kjkjk
```

I want to replace the pipe in the `col1` by a space during a select. Expected output:

```
col1  | col2
kk kk | kjkjk
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT  *,  
replace(col1,'|',' ') as col1
FROM TABLE
```

However, this generates the following:

```
col1  | col2  | col1
kk|kk | kjkjk | kk kk
```

I do not want the third column but instead, replace the content of the first column by the result of the replace statement. Is this possible?

Comment: Can the guy who downvotes at least explain why...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't  use `SELECT *`. That means return ***every*** column from the objects in the `FROM`, which includes `Col1`. You don't "replace" columns in a `SELECT`, you define then. `SELECT  *, replace(col1,'|',' ') as col1` effectively mean `SELECT Col1, Col2, replace(col1,'|',' ') as col1`.

Define your columns:

```
SELECT REPLACE(col1,'|',' ') AS col1,
       Col2
FROM dbo.[TABLE];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to lose the `*` wildcard and explicitly list out the columns you want to query:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(col1, '|', ' ') AS col1, col2
FROM   mytable
```